# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWebChannel

Tags: python, dll, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.8

I want to make an app with PyQt5.
I installed packages as

```
pyqt5==5.15.3
PyQtWebEngine==5.15.3
pyqtgraph
...
```

```py
# app.py

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QVariant, pyqtSlot, QUrl, pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel
...
```

When I execute `from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel` in cmd, it does not make an error.  
But when I execute the app with PyCharm, import error occured.

```
    from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWebChannel: the specified module could not be found
```

I checked `sys.path` before importing QtWebChannel.
Both of cmd and app have same sys.path and the sys.path are here.

```
C:\Users\Intelli2002\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python38.zip
C:\Users\Intelli2002\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\DLLs
C:\Users\Intelli2002\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib
C:\Users\Intelli2002\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38
D:\_venv
D:\_venv\lib\site-packages
D:\_venv\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.23.5-py3.8-win-amd64.egg
D:\_venv\lib\site-packages\opencv_python_headless-4.7.0.72-py3.8-win-amd64.egg
D:\_venv\lib\site-packages\win32
D:\_venv\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
D:\_venv\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
```

There are `QtWebChannel.pyd` and `QtWebChannel.pyi` files in [PyQt5 directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M31S.png)
Also, there is `QtWebChannel.dll` in [PyQt5/Qt5/bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZBTK.png)

`from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon` does not make an error, it means python could find the PyQt5 properly.
I double checked it as followings.

```py
import PyQt5
print(PyQt5.__file__) # D:_venv\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py

import PyQt5.QtCore
print(PyQt5.QtCore.__file__) # D:\_venv\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd

import PyQt5.QtGui
print(PyQt5.QtGui.__file__) # D:\_venv\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtGui.pyd
```

I repeat uninstalling and installing PyQT5. But it does not help me...

Why importing `QtWebChannel` makes an import error???

My Environments:

- OS : Windows 10
- Python : python3.8.10